# How to use .otf font files in Jekyll site

Tags: css, sass, fonts, jekyll

I have some Avenir .otf files that I want to add to use in my Jekyll site. Does anyone know how to add them? In specific:

- Which directory should I put them in?
- How to use the .otf files in my `_sass/file.scss` file?

An easy example would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend NOT using .otf fonts in production, as modern browsers may have a hard time managing them.

You can convert them to .woff and .woff2 files on [fontSquirrel's webfont generator](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator). They'll even give you the CSS

Just change the directory in the CSS to be appropriate for your site.